# How many pair solution satisfy both conditions [equation and inequation]

Tags: trigonometry

How many pair $(x,y)$ solutions satisfy these conditions: $|\tan(\pi . y)|+\sin^2(\pi x) = 0$ and $x^2+y^2\le 2$?

Answer: 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Both $|\tan(\pi y)|$ and $\sin ^2(\pi x)$ are not negative, they are $0$.

Comment: that is almost solve my question: I figure out this: $\pi y = 0$ and $\pi y = \pi$. Similarly, $\sin^2(pi.x) = 0\Rightarrow 1-\cos^2(\pi.x) = 0\Rightarrow \pi x = 0$ and $\pi x = \pi$. They have a 6 solution?